# Why Didn't Hitler order an immediate attack on Moscow in August 1941?

Tags: ww2-european-theater, moscow

In July 1941, the Soviets had begun their first organized resistance against the German invasion, after the initial German attack threw the Soviet forces into a shambles. They attempted to block the German advance by throwing most of their pre-war reserves to Smolensk and the surrounding regions.

It was a total disaster, resulting in the encirclement of over 300,000 Soviet troops, though it did slow the German advance. Moscow was up for grabs, and this, while unlikely to finish off the Soviets, would have been a massive morale advantage for the Axis. The Soviets did have some troops mobilized in the centre to attempt to block this threat, however they would not be enough, they were not very well trained and were essentially ordered to throw themselves at the enemy if things went badly.

However, instead of pressing this advantage, the armored formations of the Army Group Center, which would be vital for any offensive, were dispersed across the front to aid neighbouring army groups North and South, which were not progressing as nicely as the center. Yes, taking Moscow would create a long salient in the axis lines, but they had no problem doing this in previous attacks, and it would usually work out well for the Axis. Yes, the large encirclement at Kiev/Kyiv would likely not be done, but the south was not of great concern, and the other two army groups were targeting much more important targets(Leningrad, Murmansk[arguably a separate front, but we will count it here], Moscow).

The south would also likely pull off some smaller encirclements similar to the encirclement at Uman, and gain an effect similar to the one large Kiev/Kyiv(I don't know which one it is at this point) encirclement. Mud was also a problem, but that was far from a deciding factor in any event. And finally, Moscow was a symbol, and German leaders were obsessed with symbols. This is further proven at the Battle of Stalingrad, where German soldiers were fighting in house-to-house combat over what, at this point, was quite literally a pile of rubble, due to the symbol that Stalingrad represented, and the morale/propaganda victories that would come with it.

What made the Axis prefer the northern and southern sectors over an attack on Moscow in August, after they had defeated the Soviets at Smolensk? If nothing else, this would have crushed the already weakened Soviet morale, and rendered much of the Red Army, much of it already barely trained and demoralized, borderline useless against the Germans with superior training, a major supply hub taken from the enemy, and a morale increase like nothing else could do. What stopped the Axis from jumping on the opportunity to take Moscow in August of 1941?

PS; I'm not questioning the strategic aspect, which, securing the flanks alone would have been a good reason to disperse the army group. I was asking, why did Hitler, who was obsessed with symbols and political victories above strategic ones, and who had full control over the Wehrmacht, order a dispersion of the army group, rather than attacking what Hitler was likely to believe to be the most important objective of Operation Barbarossa?

Comment: Please explain what's missing from Wikipedia's article on the [Battle of Moscow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Moscow)?

Comment: @JohnDallman I would vote for re-opening the question: wikipedia articles give elements to explain a decision,but they always could be discussed

Answer (score 2):

There were by that time very important military factors that literally obliterated any politic or symbolic considerations:

- First, Soviet resistance on Smolensk: while the Germans did manage to encircle **some** Soviet troops there, the Soviets had massed largely more to stop fight from the inside as well as the outside the German forces. And they fought efficiently: German tank divisions were exhausted by the fierce fight, lacking infantry and artillery support. Just after the end of the encirclement, Soviets led counterstrikes that failed but continued to harass the Germans. So it is wrong to think that the road to Moscow was open. It was closed, full of Soviet soldiers
- Second, the opportunity of Kiev: Mocow was so tightly protected that the Germans identified the possible failure in the South, at Roslav. Some Germans still wanted to use it to go back North and re-attack on Moscow direction,  but it soon appeared easier to continue South
- Third, the situation in UKraine was bad: the Germans had heavy problems with their advance, so the help from the Center Group would very useful. That is what ultimately devided the advance on Kiev

This is the answer. Now I would like to highlight in your question the wrong premises:

- *instead of pressing this advantage* : there was no specific advantage after the battle of Smolensk As I said before, this was a fierce battle with heavy German losses as well.
- *but the south was not of great concern* : initial German plans about the attack of USSR did not focus especially on Moscow, Leningrad or Ukraine: in fact, the Germans had no clear priorities and that is why the ultimate plan was a three-prongs attack. South, Ukraine was very important: this was food resources, then industrial resources (Donbass), ultimately oil resources (Caucasus). The Germans needed them so their nearly stalled advance in Ukraine could not be let aside.